# Antiderivative of CDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $F(x)$ be the CDF of a random variable. Does its antiderivative

$$
\int_{-\infty}^x F(x') dx'
$$

have an interpretation?

Comment: Not usually. Most commonly, it's the other way around. The derivative of $F_X(t)$ with respect to $t$ is density function $f_X(t)$ of $X.$

Comment: Not that I know of, I will say that integral doesn't always exist in the first place

Comment: @AlexPavellas why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sort of.  If $X$ is an r.v. with this distribution, then this integral is equal to
$\mathop{E}(x-X)^+$ (where $y^+ = max(0,y)$).

This is easy to see in the case $X$ has a density with respect to
Lebesgue measure:
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^x F(y)dy &=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty 1_{y<x} \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z) 1_{z<y}
dz\right) dy\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z) \int_{-\infty}^\infty 1_{z<y<x} \quad dy\; dz\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z) (x-z)^+ dz\\
&= \mathop{E} (x-X)^+
\end{align}
but it actually holds for arbitrary $X$.

A related observation that admits a more natural interpretation is that, for a non-negative r.v. X, the antiderivative of the survival function $S(x) = 1-F(x)$ calculated from lower bound $x=0$ satisfies
$$\int_0^x S(x) dx = \mathop{E}[X; X<x]$$
where $\mathop{E}[Y; A] \equiv \mathop{E}[Y 1_A]$ is the restricted expectation.  In particular:
$$\int_0^\infty S(x) dx = \mathop{E}[X]$$